# R data frame row name shows matrix instead of numeric value

Tags: r, dataframe, r-rownames

I have the following to create a data frame.  My problem is that the data frame row names display as [1,],[2,],[3,],[4,], etc instead of just 1,2,3,4,etc (see below for outputs).  Why and how can I fix this to just have my row names show as usual (incremented number).

```
Code:

df <- data.frame(id=c("id"),nobs=c("nobs"))
df <- cbind(id,nobs)
df
```

id and nobs are two vectors with 5 numeric values each...

```
Current output:
     id nobs
[1,]  2 3653
[2,]  4 3653
[3,]  8 1462
[4,] 10 1097
[5,] 12  732

Desired output:
   id nobs
1  2 3653
2  4 3653
3  8 1462
4 10 1097
5 12  732
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I don't suggest that you should use either of these methods. If you want a `data.frame`, you can create it directly as Paul has showed (or you yourself have done). This is just to illustrate why this happens. Although sometimes when using `sapply` for example, the output would be a matrix and you might want to bind 2 such matrices and have them as a `data.frame`.

From the help page for `cbind` (`?cbind`):

> The functions cbind and rbind are S3 generic, with methods for data frames. The data frame method will be used if at least one argument is a data frame and the rest are vectors or matrices.
>
> **Data frame methods**
>
> The cbind data frame method is just a wrapper for data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE). This means that it will split matrix columns in data frame arguments, and convert character columns to factors unless stringsAsFactors = FALSE is specified.

So, if you pass two vectors, the wrapper for `data.frame` won't be called. Hence, you obtain a matrix.

> What can you do?
>   1) you could create and pass *at least one* `data.frame` argument to `cbind`
>   2) wrap the `cbind` argument with a `as.data.frame(.)`.

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 6:10
> cbind(data.frame(x), y)
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10

> as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

Comment: Thank you Arun! This was helpful.  I'm new to R and now I see how the built in help actually is useful.  I suspected it but just wasn't sure.  Also, sorry if I did not

Answer (score 4):

Your second command completely overwrites the first. What you want is

```
df <- data.frame(id=id, nobs=nobs)
```

Since your inputs to [cbind](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/cbind.html) are vectors (I presume), then by default it returns a matrix.

Additionally you could force it as a data frame via

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(id, nobs))
```

but that is overkill.

Comment: +1 For recommending the use of `data.frame()` directly. Too many people get sucked into the vortex of using `cbind` to build data frames when it isn't necessary, and usually just causes problems.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  That worked and I understand better now.  Also, sorry if I did not make your answer the selected one.  I just went with the first one I saw from Arun.